# Is there a way to specify special characters, specifically ae ligature, in the content part of a ::before pseudoclass

Tags: css

```
.formulae::before {
    content: "Formul&aelig;: "
}
```

It doesn't appear that I can use `&aelig;` (æ) as shown. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just put the character in there directly?  You could also use the unicode version which is `\00E6`

```css
.formulae1::before {
    content: "Formulæ: "
}
.formulae2::before {
    content: "Formul\00E6: "
}
```

```html
<div class="formulae1">test</div>
<div class="formulae2">test</div>
```